# System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте. У меня такая проблема есть. В запущенной программе есть одно место, где дает ошибку, вот детали этой ошибки. Как ее исправить?

> `See the end of this message for details on invoking 
> just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> `************** Exception Text **************
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>    at Mari.MagazineSale.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)`

Answer (score 1):

В **Mari.MagazineSale.button1_Click** Вы обращаетесь к переменной значение которой null. приведите код метода **Mari.MagazineSale.button1_Click**, можно будет сказать яснее :-)

Comment: А почему на одной машине программа нормально работает, а на другой - не работает?

Comment: Ну наверное на одной что-то есть (файлы девайсы и пр.) на другой нету.

Comment: А можно эти файлы добавить?

Comment: Ничего страшного от этого не будет :-D Приведите код метода, если хотите получить более развёрнутый ответ.